# Assembly call subprograms based on user input

Tags: linux, assembly, input, x86, att

I have a program that is supposed to either add or subtract two hardcoded numbers based on user input `0` or `not 0`. I get memory access violation error inside `input`. when i try to `call sum` or `call diff` instead `input` in line 9 it works fine and gives me expected output. `loop` and `next` is used to display result from stack.

```
.text

.global _start

_start:

xorl %esi, %esi     # zerowanie licznika

call input          #  <----  line 9

loop:               # label
movl $0, %edx       # reszta z dzielenia
movl $10, %ebx      # dzielnik
divl %ebx           # dzielenie, wynik w eax, reszta w edx
addl $48, %edx      # kod ASCII
pushl %edx          # edx na stos
incl %esi           # esi++
cmpl $0, %eax       # porównaj wynik i 0
jz   next           # jeśli koniec, jump next
jmp loop            # jeśli nie, następna iteracja

next:               # label
cmpl $0, %esi       # porównaj licznik z 0
jz   exit           # jeśli koniec, jump exit
decl %esi           # esi--
movl $4, %eax       # kod 4 = zapis
movl %esp, %ecx     # znak do wypisania
movl $1, %ebx       # domyślny strumień - sys_out
movl $1, %edx       # długość stringa do wypisania? 
int  $0x80          # przerwanie
addl $4, %esp       # 
jmp  next           # kolejna iteracja

exit:
mov $1, %eax        # zakończenie programu
mov $0, %ebx        # kod wyjścia
int $0x80           # przerwanie


# ---------------- subprogram ----------------------

input:
movl $3, %eax          # code 3 = input
movl $0, %ebx          # code 0 = stdin
subl $4, %esp          # move stack pointer by 4 bytes
movl %esp, %ecx        # set reading position onto stack
movl $4, %edx          # read 4 bytes
int  $0x80             # interrupt to execute above

cmp %esp, '0'          # if(input == '0') sum else diff
jz sum                 
jnz diff
ret

sum:
movl $37, %eax      # pierwsza liczba sumy
movl $22, %ebx      # druga liczba sumy
addl %ebx, %eax     # suma, wynik w eax
ret

diff:
movl $37, %eax      # pierwsza liczba sumy
movl $22, %ebx      # druga liczba sumy
subl %ebx, %eax     # roznica, wynik w eax
ret

# -------------     end    -------------
```

How can I edit my `input` function to read a character/number and compare it to `0`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`cmp %esp, '0'` is wrong, because it tries to compare the value of `%esp` to the value in memory at address `'0'`. At&t syntax uses reversed operands, and it needs a `$` prefix for immediates. But you already know this, I guess you were just a little careless. The correct instruction is `cmpb $'0', (%esp)` to compare the byte in memory at address `%esp` to the ascii code of `0`.

Furthermore, you allocated 4 bytes from the stack, but you never free that. When you eventually hit a `ret` it will use your local variable as return address which is of course a bad thing :)  A nice trick is to use `lea 4(%esp), %esp` to free it without affecting the flags, so you can do this between the `cmp` and the `jz`. If you like less tricky stuff, you can of course just pop the input into a register and use that in the comparison, such as:

```
pop %eax
cmp $'0', %al
```

PS: Learn to use a debugger. That would have pointed you directly at the instruction, and then you probably could have figured out the problem yourself.